# General input/output error ? how to solve when the excel sheet?

Tags: php, yii-extensions

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel1.JPhpExcel');

$xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');

$xls->addArray($sheet_generation);

$xls->generateXML('my-test');
```

In controller :

```
 $get_user_info=$model->userInfo();

     ######  Sheet generation
     $sheet_generation=$model->sheetInfo($get_user_info,$month,$year);
```

In model:-

```
public function sheetInfo($user_info,$sel_month,$sel_year)
    {

      $cnt=0;

      foreach($user_info as $key => $line) {

      $cnt=$cnt+1;
                        $linearr = $line;


                        //$linearr['heading']='';

                        //$linearr['imagess']='';


                        //array_push($linearr, "apple", "raspberry");
                        //print_r($linearr); exit;

                        $p=$line['Place'];
                        $place=Sheet::getWorkin($p);
                        $userid=$line['id'];

                        // Total present days

                        $no_days=Sheet::getPresent($userid,$sel_month,$sel_year);

                        $disti=$line['Designation'];
                        //designation names...............
                        $designation=Sheet::detDesignationName($disti);
                        /// Department name display..............
                        $d=$line['Department']; 
                        $depart=Sheet:: getDepartmantName($d);
                        // Holiday
                        $holiday=Sheet::getHolidayDat($sel_month,$sel_year);
                        $approval=2;
                        $leave_count=Sheet::getLeaveCount($userid,$sel_month,$sel_year,$approval);
                        ###### sunday leave count 
                        $sunday=Sheet::sunday_count($sel_month,$sel_year);
                        ########saturday count
                        $sat_count=Sheet::saturday_count($sel_month,$sel_year);
                        $sat_sunday_count=Sheet::weekday_count($userid,$sel_month,$sel_year);

                        //$heading="Attendance Report January 2014";

                        //$linearr['heading']=Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl/images/."favicon.ico";
                        //$linearr['Sno']=$cnt;
                        $linearr['Place']=$place;
                        $linearr['Designation'] =$designation;
                        $linearr['Department'] =$depart;
                        $sum_present=$sum_present+$no_days; // sum of present days....................
                        $linearr['present'] =$no_days;
                        $linearr['holiday'] =$holiday;
                        $linearr['leave'] =$leave_count;
                        $linearr['weekoffice'] =$sat_sunday_count;
                        $linearr['lop'] =0;

                        $resarr[] = $linearr;
            }
            //print_r($resarr); exit;
            return $resarr;


    }
```

Comment: What's the error? Where?

Comment: When i open the excel sheet,it show the error

Comment: I dont know the error place

Comment: Can you open the generated excel file in notepad, and see what is inside? WHat is the size of the file?

Comment: nothing display in the notepad.

Comment: Well, there you go, your excel creation fails. Check if there are errors in your log and see what does that show.

Comment: General error  GeneralInput.output error

Comment: $sheet_generation gives the related values. but i can't open the excel file